# Windows 8 CRITICAL_SERVICE_FAILED bsod

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, bsod

I've got into a BSOD situation where windows 8.1 64bit is giving CRITICAL_SERVICE_FAILED error. I got into this scenario after having put windows 8 on standby , and the next time on bootloader (I have a dual boot windows 8 and window 7) i selected windows 7 (i had forgotten windows 8 was put to sleep and not shutdown) and so when win7 was starting it ran a check disk on the windows 8 partition and must have made some changes ("repaired" it) . Not sure how i can fix this or if it's fixable at all. Any advise besides doing a fresh windows 8 install?

I have tried doing a repair install but it tells me the "drive is locked" .

Comment: So I assume by standby you mean hibernate. Usually, the boot manager will be locked when Windows is hibernating. Does it still not boot?

Comment: share the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump so that we can see more details.